# How to sendMail using nodemail and smtp transport?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I have new user registration once i get user detail from client i am sending email to group to grant permission to user , Below code is throwing exception any idea what is implemented wrong ?

I have pasted error in question.

Mailer.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var MAIL_SERVER_URL = '127.0.0.0'; 


//establish the transporter
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: MAIL_SERVER_URL,
    port: 80,
    connectionTimeout: 60000,
}));

var Mailer = {
      options: function (mailOptions) {
        mailOptions.to = 'group@gmail.com';
        mailOptions.text = mailOptions.auid + ''+ 'requested access for modeler';
        console.log('mailOptions',mailOptions);
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
                    if (error) {
                        return console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                    }
        });
      }
}



module.exports = Mailer;
```

Error

```
{ [Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.0:25]
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.0',
  port: 80,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error output is telling you that `nodemailer` cannot access the SMTP server at `127.0.0.0` on port 25.

Your implementation of nodemailer using SMTP looks good assuming the mailOptions getting passed in has a `from` property. You can read more about SMTP through nodemailer in [the docs](https://nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/setup-smtp/).

```
let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let MAIL_SERVER_URL = '127.0.0.0';
let smtp = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: MAIL_SERVER_URL,
    connectionTimeout: 60000
});

module.exports = {
    options: (mailOptions) => {
        let email = {
            from: 'from@test.com',
            to: 'group@gmail.com',
            subject: 'yourEmailSubject'
            text: `${mailOptions.auid} requested access for modeler`
        };
        smtp.sendMail(email, (err, info) => {
            if (err) 
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log(`Message sent: ${info.response}`);

        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I am using `MAIL_SERVER_URL` to send email. Do i still need `from` property to be part of mailOptions ? currently from is not mailOptions property.

Comment: Yes, the from is the sender of the address, `MAIL_SERVER_URL` is simply the location of the SMTP host which, is used to create your mail transport. In your code `mailOptions` represents the email being sent using your mail transport.

Comment: so from can be part of `mailOptions` , in user detail i have user email that i can use as from address  that would `mailOptions.from`

Comment: @hussain checkout my updated answer, added a code sample. Also you need to fix your smtp transport. It doesn't look right. SMTP operates on port 25 not 80.

Comment: the way you coded i am getting an error `transport` is not a function. so even after adding `from` property in my code i am still getting an error i have mentioned in question.port is corrected.

Comment: @hussain apologies, there was a typo in the transport creation. I was missing the `create` prior to transport, that example should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i still got this error `{ [Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:25]
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 25,
  command: 'CONN' }
`

Comment: @hussain Like I say in the first sentence of my answer. You need to actually have an SMTP server running at 127.0.0.0:25 which you don't it seems

Comment: i tried 2 other servers i got same errors , let me check and make sure servers are running

Answer (score 0):

> SMTP mail send using xoauth

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: "Gmail",
                auth: {
                  type: "OAuth2",
                  user: credential.email,
                  clientId: credential.clientId,
                  clientSecret: credential.clientSecret,
                  refreshToken: credential.refreshToken,
                },
              });

 smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
```